# Digital Ocean Droplet Crash after Resize. I am unable to figure out the issue

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, server-crashes, digital-ocean, ubuntu-22.04

I am currently running an Apache2 web server with FastCGI Process Manager (PHP-FPM) on Ubuntu 22.04 at Digital Ocean. Recently, I wanted to add an additional website to the server. To do this, I decided to use their Resize tool to upgrade the plan. However, after the resize, all the services went down, making it impossible for me to access the server via SSH. The server has been down for the past 24 hours, and I am unable to figure out the issue.

I can only access the server through their Recovery Console, which has limited options and is extremely slow. Please bear with me.

**/var/log/apache2/error.log**
The server went down after logging the last line in the Apache error log. No additional lines were logged.
[image]

It seems that the `/var/log/syslog` file did not record any activity for a few hours before the server resizing occurred.

**NMAP port 22**

```
kevin@192 ~ % nmap -p 22 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -Pn
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-28 11:11 IST
Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
Host is up (0.062s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp closed ssh
```

`ss -plnt` **output**
[image]

`ufw status verbose` **output**
[image]

`grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config` **output**
[image]

**Services status inactive (dead)**
[image]

**I am unable to restart any of the services.**
[image]

`lsblk` **output**
[image]

Any assistance that can help bring my server back online would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else I should include.